# Pgrouting (QGIS) multiple point

Tags: pgrouting, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have read al lot of the pgrouting, but i still not quite sure if it can do what i want.

I have 20 stop points and i have 1 starting point and 1 finish point. 
I want to calculate the shortest path between starting point, all 20 stop point and finish point.

Its something like delivering packects, so from starting point to point x then point y and last finish point,

Maybe iets possible with a dijkstra algorimte ?